# join to tables on a condition and return that data that against with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table(`table1`, `table2`). now i wanna to read all form `table1` if `field1` equal to `table2`.`filed2` and if not equal.

I hope understand my problem.

I need to read all of `table1` data and read `table2` filed if have relation or key in `table1`.

how i can get all of data just with a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a LEFT JOIN. LEFT join will bring you all the result from the table which is in the left side of the JOIN clause and matching records from the Table which is in the right side of the JOIN based on the  matching criteria mentioned in the ON condition . If there is no match query will return you NULL values for the selected columns of the table in the right side of the JOIN condition.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM table1 t1
   LEFT  JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.Field1=t2.Field2
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `OUTER JOIN` to do that and it was exactly that i want.

Comment: Please add this as a comment or include in your question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Make a left join between two table on **primary key**  who has same data on both table like

```
Select * from table1 AS table1 with(nolock) 
LEFT join table2 AS table2 
on  table1.nameofprimaryKey= table2.nameofprimarykey
```